# SNS confirmSubscription using NodeJs with Express

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-sns

I am trying to set up a subscription to an SNS topic, I have added the HTTP subscription in the SNS UI and it is labeled as "Pending Confirmation". I have set up my endpoint to look for the correct header (shown below) and that is working. My issue is that the Endpoint never gets the "Token", see below my code and the output from the logs.

NodeJS (w/ express 4.15) code for testing:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('-----------------')
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.headers)
    console.log('-----------------')
    if (req.get('x-amz-sns-message-type') == "SubscriptionConfirmation") {
        SNS.confirmSubscription({ Token: req.body.Token, TopicArn: req.get('x-amz-sns-topic-arn') }, (err, finished) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
        })
    } else {
        console.log(req.body)
    }
})
```

POST Request from AWS

```
-----------------
{}
{ host: 'myapp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com',
  'x-real-ip': '172.XXX.40.XXX',
  'x-forwarded-for': '54.240.XXX.XXX, 172.XXX.40.XXX',
  'content-length': '1604',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
  'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
  'user-agent': 'Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent',
  'x-amz-sns-message-id': '493b2a00-a99f-4cf3-ac9a-aad8ad6ee115',
  'x-amz-sns-message-type': 'SubscriptionConfirmation',
  'x-amz-sns-topic-arn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:4868XXXXXXXX:mysnstopic',
  'x-forwarded-port': '80',
  'x-forwarded-proto': 'http' }
-----------------

{ InvalidParameter: Invalid token
    at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
  message: 'Invalid token',
  code: 'InvalidParameter',
  time: 2018-08-13T17:32:15.516Z,
  requestId: '6945a62f-c746-5785-8497-f5c4059943ab',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 50.366310913093 }
```

Above, you will see that `req.body` is empty and the headers are set but no `Token` is included. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You have to explicitly inform express to use text parsing for this endpoint.

Try this:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const request = require('request');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')


    router.post('/',bodyParser.text(),handleSNSMessage);
    module.exports = router;


    var handleSubscriptionResponse = function (error, response) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('Yess! We have accepted the confirmation from AWS');
        }
        else {
            throw new Error(`Unable to subscribe to given URL`);
            //console.error(error)
        }
    }
    async function handleSNSMessage(req, resp, next) {

        try {
            let payloadStr = req.body
            payload = JSON.parse(payloadStr)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(payload))
            if (req.header('x-amz-sns-message-type') === 'SubscriptionConfirmation') {
                const url = payload.SubscribeURL;
                await request(url, handleSubscriptionResponse)
            } else if (req.header('x-amz-sns-message-type') === 'Notification') {
                console.log(payload)
                //process data here
            } else {
                throw new Error(`Invalid message type ${payload.Type}`);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
            resp.status(500).send('Oops')
        }
        resp.send('Ok')
    }
```

Edit: express v4.17.0 onwards you can use express.text() middleware itself, instead of bodyParser.text(). Take a look at [this official doc](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.text)

**Note:** I didn't use `app.use` as that will impact all my other endpoints.

Comment: at newer versions of express, we can also use `express.text()` instead `bodyParser.text()`, as the last one is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

> **AWS will send the post request to your http endpoint not the get request.**

Sample post request you will Recieve from aws sns service:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
x-amz-sns-message-type: SubscriptionConfirmation
x-amz-sns-message-id: 165545c9-2a5c-472c-8df2-7ff2be2b3b1b
x-amz-sns-topic-arn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic
Content-Length: 1336
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent

{
  "Type" : "SubscriptionConfirmation",
  "MessageId" : "165545c9-2a5c-472c-8df2-7ff2be2b3b1b",
  "Token" : "2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e241d09c805a5a57b30d712f794cc5f6a988666d92768dd60a747ba6f3beb71854e285d6ad02428b09ceece29417f1f02d609c582afbacc99c583a916b9981dd2728f4ae6fdb82efd087cc3b7849e05798d2d2785c03b0879594eeac82c01f235d0e717736",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic",
  "Message" : "You have chosen to subscribe to the topic arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic.\nTo confirm the subscription, visit the SubscribeURL included in this message.",
  "SubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=ConfirmSubscription&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic&Token=2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e241d09c805a5a57b30d712f794cc5f6a988666d92768dd60a747ba6f3beb71854e285d6ad02428b09ceece29417f1f02d609c582afbacc99c583a916b9981dd2728f4ae6fdb82efd087cc3b7849e05798d2d2785c03b0879594eeac82c01f235d0e717736",
  "Timestamp" : "2012-04-26T20:45:04.751Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "EXAMPLEpH+DcEwjAPg8O9mY8dReBSwksfg2S7WKQcikcNKWLQjwu6A4VbeS0QHVCkhRS7fUQvi2egU3N858fiTDN6bkkOxYDVrY0Ad8L10Hs3zH81mtnPk5uvvolIC1CXGu43obcgFxeL3khZl8IKvO61GWB6jI9b5+gLPoBc1Q=",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem"
  }
```

You have to confirm the subscription from your http/https endpoint.

please go through the url below will give you step by step guide to do it and also help you and clear your doubts for token:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html#SendMessageToHttp.subscribe

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I just did not include that in my code, but it is a POST method in express.

Comment: @gregwinn any progress on this issue?

Comment: @IonTichy, no I am sorry... I have opened issues with AWS and they are looking into my account (they feel it might be an issue with something there...) I will update this question when if I find a solution!

Comment: I worked around the problem by using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser middleware.